# Add unique rows for each group when similar group repeats after certain rows

Tags: t-sql

Hi Can anyone help me please to get unique group number?

I need to give unique rows for each group even when same group repeats after some groups.
I have following data:

```
id  version product startdate   enddate
123 0       2443    2010/09/01  2011/01/02          
123 1       131     2011/01/03  2011/03/09
123 2       131     2011/08/10  2012/09/10
123 3       3009    2012/09/11  2014/03/31
123 4       668     2014/04/01  2014/04/30
123 5       668     2014/05/01  2016/01/01
123 6       668     2016/01/02  2017/09/08
123 7       131     2017/09/09  2017/10/10
123 8       131     2018/10/11  2019/01/01
123 9       550     2019/01/02  2099/01/01

select *,
dense_rank()over(partition by id order by id,product)
from table
```

Expected results:

```
id  version product startdate   enddate      count
123 0       2443    2010/09/01  2011/01/02  1       
123 1       131     2011/01/03  2011/03/09  2
123 2       131     2011/08/10  2012/09/10  2
123 3       3009    2012/09/11  2014/03/31  3
123 4       668     2014/04/01  2014/04/30  4
123 5       668     2014/05/01  2016/01/01  4
123 6       668     2016/01/02  2017/09/08  4
123 7       131     2017/09/09  2017/10/10  5 
123 8       131     2018/10/11  2019/01/01  5
123 9       550     2019/01/02  2099/01/01  6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT
  id,version,product,startdate,enddate,
  1+SUM(v)OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY version) n
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      IIF(LAG(product)OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY version)<>product,1,0) v
    FROM TestTable
  ) q
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sergey. I am new to sql programming. It helped me a lot. :)